# how to change the position of the dropdown of Lightning combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-combobox

can we change the dropdown box align with combobox? is it possible?

it is like this now.
[image]

I want it like this
[image]

```
<td class="slds-cell_action-mode" role="gridcell">
                                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="MarketOptions">
                                                 <lightning-combobox
                                                     class="combostyle"
                                                     name={item.id}
                                                     label="Options"
                                                     value={item.selectedOption}
                                                     options={lst}
                                                     onchange={handlePicklistChange}
                                                     placeholder="Select Market"
                                                     variant="label-hidden">
                                                 </lightning-combobox>
                                             </div>
                                         </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lightning-combobox, we can control dropdown alignment using `dropdown-alignment` attribute as shown below :

```
<lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            label="Status"
            value=""
            placeholder="Select Progress"
            options={options}
            onchange={handleChange}
            dropdown-alignment="left"
            variant="label-hidden"
    ></lightning-combobox>
```

Default value for `dropdown-alignment` attribute is left, not sure why its showing to the right.

For responsive design , use `auto` as `dropdown-alignment`

More info - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification